# Speed up construction of large matrix with if statements

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, tensors, sparse-arrays

I am constructing a matrix of the form
$$
T_{i_aj_ak_al_a,i_bj_bk_bl_b} = T_{i_ai_b}\delta_{j_aj_b}\delta_{k_ak_b}\delta_{l_al_b} + T_{j_aj_b}\delta_{i_ai_b}\delta_{k_ak_b}\delta_{l_al_b} + T_{k_ak_b}\delta_{i_ai_b}\delta_{j_aj_b}\delta_{l_al_b} + T_{l_al_b}\delta_{i_ai_b}\delta_{j_aj_b}\delta_{k_ak_b}
$$

with

$$
T_{i_ai_b} = \frac{\hbar^2 (-1)^{i_a-i_b}}{2m_w \Delta w^2} \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \dfrac{\pi^2}{3},  & i_a = i_b \\ \dfrac{2}{(i_a-i_b)^2}, & i_a \neq i_b \end{array} \right\}
$$

I did this in *Mathematica* with the following code:

```
Twxyz =
  SparseArray[
   Flatten[
    Table[
     If[ia == ib,
        \[Pi]^2/3,
        2/(ia - ib)^2]*(hbar^2*(-1)^(ia - ib))/(2 mw *dw^2)*
       KroneckerDelta[ja, jb]*KroneckerDelta[ka, kb]*
       KroneckerDelta[la, lb]
      +
      If[ja == jb,
        \[Pi]^2/3,
        2/(ja - jb)^2]*(hbar^2*(-1)^(ja - jb))/(2 mx*dx^2)*
       KroneckerDelta[ia, ib]*KroneckerDelta[ka, kb]*
       KroneckerDelta[la, lb]
      +
      If[ka == kb,
        \[Pi]^2/3,
        2/(ka - kb)^2]*(hbar^2*(-1)^(ka - kb))/(2 my*dy^2)*
       KroneckerDelta[ia, ib]*KroneckerDelta[ja, jb]*
       KroneckerDelta[la, lb]
      +
      If[la == lb,
        \[Pi]^2/3,
        2/(la - lb)^2]*(hbar^2*(-1)^(la - lb))/(2 mz*dz^2)*
       KroneckerDelta[ia, ib]*KroneckerDelta[ja, jb]*
       KroneckerDelta[ka, kb]
     ,
     {lb, npointsgrid},
     {la, npointsgrid},
     {kb, npointsgrid},
     {ka, npointsgrid},
     {jb, npointsgrid},
     {ja, npointsgrid},
     {ib, npointsgrid},
     {ia, npointsgrid}]
    , {{1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}}]
   ];
```

This approach works ok. The problem is that it takes several hours to build the matrix due to the many if statements it must process for each matrix element. Any suggestions on how to speed up the matrix construction?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The table is numeric.

Typical values for variables are

```
hbar = 6.62607004*^-34/(2*Pi)
npointsgrid = 13
mx*dx^2 = 3.76547*^-49
```

In the end, the matrix is constructed such that $$ m_w\Delta w^2 = m_x\Delta x^2 = m_y \Delta y^2 = m_z \Delta z^2$$

```
In[307]:= mw*dw^2
          mx*dx^2
          my*dy^2
          mz*dz^2

Out[307]= 3.76547*10^-49

Out[308]= 3.76547*10^-49

Out[309]= 3.76547*10^-49

Out[310]= 3.76547*10^-49
```

EDIT 2:

Correction of LaTeX code: should be $\hbar^2$ in definition of T, not $\hbar$ as previously written.

Comment: You can use `Piecewise`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `KroneckerProduct`:

```
hbar = 6.62607004*^-34/(2*Pi);
npointsgrid = 2;
mwdw2 = 3.76547*^-49;

npointsgrid = 13;

T = Table[((hbar^2 (-1)^(ia - ib)) Piecewise[{{π^2/3, ia == ib}}, 2/(ia - ib)^2])/(
   2 mwdw2), {ia, npointsgrid}, {ib, npointsgrid}];

kro = SparseArray@Array[KroneckerDelta, {npointsgrid, npointsgrid}];

Twxyztest = 
   KroneckerProduct @@ RotateLeft[{T, kro, kro, kro}, #] & /@ Range@4 // 
    Total; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.109369, Null} *)
```

The validity can be easily checked by choosing a smaller `npointsgrid`. (For `npointsgrid = 5`, the original code takes about 12 seconds to finish calculating. )

Comment: Thanks, that works really well. I knew there must be some product I could use because the matrix is rather sparse.

Comment: @de_thom_22 Glad it helps. If this answer solves your problem, you may accept it by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).